# Unfortunate auto-detection of "synonyms" for "initializer{_,-}list".

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There is some unfortunate mechanism that merges tags `initializer-list` and `initializer_list`. In the new upcoming C++ Standard, these have quite different meanings and usage patterns, and are about different problem domains

```
class IntList {
public:
  // This is a constructor that accepts an
  // initializer_list, which is a language-magic type supporting
  // iteration over a homogeneous initializer list 
  List(initializer_list<int>);
};

// { 1, 2, 3 } is an initializer list.
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

// {{"foo", 42}, {"bar", 43}} is an initializer list.
map<string, int> m = {{"foo", 42}, {"bar", 43}};
```

I'm not sure whether it's worth-while to introduce a special case for this, but it seems harmful to merge these two things, since the majority of uses of these two words will refer to the "initializer-list" case, but I still see significant cases of "initializer_list" (which is also the header file where the `initializer_list` class is defined in).

To be pedantic, there are three things, but I suspect "initializer-list" will, as the "-" is commonly used to serve as a space for tags, be used to mean "initializer list"

- **initializer list** refers to the whole brace-enclosed thing - that is `{ 1, 2, 3 }`.
- **initializer-list** refers to the grammar that parses the content of the brace enclosed thing - that is, `1, 2, 3`.
- **initializer_list** refers to the type that a constructor or function can use to iterate over a homogeneous initializer list - that is `std::initializer_list<>`.

Comment: For example question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757614/why-doesnt-my-template-accept-an-initializer-list List for the tag shows usage of both things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initializer-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would personally use <kbd>stdinitializer-list</kbd> for the case of `std::initializer_list<>` (like we use <kbd>stdvector</kbd> for `std::vector<>`) and <kbd>initializer-list</kbd>  for the language construct.

I changed my question to use that scheme.

Comment: c++ stdvector ×57, [c++ vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20vector) ×866

Comment: I would appreciate help on the wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdinitializerlist/info

Answer (score 2):

The problem with "correct" tagging is that tagging isn't and can't be perfect. Usage dictates tags, not the other way round; synonyms can nudge usage towards correctness but only by so much. That's why people can retag.

Since there can't be spaces in tags, the standard is to use dashes instead, hence there's no hope of separating `initializer-list` and `initializer list`; tag the latter [grammar](/questions/tagged/grammar) instead :)

As for the other tag, [tag:initializer_list], [there's actually no synonym rule in place.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=list) All underscores are turned into dashes automatically. So, there's also no hope of separating `initializer-list` from `initializer_list`.

I'm no C++ master, but I think this is akin to splitting hairs. They're all the same thing seen from three different points: grammar, type and... er... grammar again. If distinguishing is this important, use a second tag :)

Comment: I've an idea. I think i will use `std::initializer_list` for the other case! They are not really the same. It's like the difference between `{1, 2, 3}` and `std::vector<int>`. An `std::initializer_list<int>` is actually much more like a `std::vector<int>`. An initializer list is just a language construct.

Comment: Of course this is splitting hair. We're the C++ crowd, so what did you expect?

Comment: @johannes Nice try, but will people use the `stdinitializer-list` tag? :)

Comment: @badp you can help make it happen: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdinitializerlist/info

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don't actually know any C++ :)